# Flask Mail, Duplicate mails being sent

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-mail

I am using Python and Flask Mail. I am trying to send a welcome email after the user confirms his account via clicking on a link sent as an email to the user earlier for confirming his account. After confirming his account by changing the value of the confirmed entry to true in the database, I send the welcome email. But it is sending 5 duplicate emails instead of one.

I used the below code-

```
class AccountConfirmation(Resource):
    @jwt_required    
    def post(self):
        current_user_id = get_jwt_identity()
        user = User.query.get(current_user_id)
        user.confirmed = True
        db.session.commit()
        send_welcome_email(user)
        return {'msg': 'Account confirmed successfully. You can now login to your account'}, 200 

def send_welcome_email(user):
    subject = '...'
    body = '...'
    sender = Config.ADMINS[0]
    recipients = [user.email_id]
    send_email(subject, body, sender, recipients)

from flask_mail import Message
def send_email(subject, body, sender, recipients):
    msg = Message(subject = subject, body = body, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    mail.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any problem with the code. Except if there are multiple request to send the mail. To get over it, you can try sending Asynchronous Email. Please check this piece of code and don't forget to check the [link](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support) for better explanation.

```
from threading import Thread
# ...

def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)


def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    Thread(target=send_async_email, args=(app, msg)).start()
```